# How to use multiple Arduino boards with a single Raspberry Pi for sending and receiving data?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am doing a project that involves using a Raspberry Pi to control all the switchboards in my house. I will start by wiring three switchboards first.

I am planning to use one 8-channel and one 2-channel relay for each of the switchboards, as each of these switchboards contain 10 switches. So, that amounts to 30 relay units.

However, I do not have as many as 30 free GPIO pins on my Raspberry Pi. I can use a port expander, but the Pi is installed with a camera and stationed near a door and fixed there. So, all the 30 wires from the switchboards need to be brought to the Pi, which will make the walls look messy. I was wondering if I could install an Arduino mini for each of the switchboards and control the relays using the Arduinos.

The Arduinos in that case need to the connected to the Raspberry Pi somehow such that when I want to switch on a specific light in my bedroom, I send a command to the Pi. The Pi sends the corresponding information to the Arduino in some well-defined format, like JSON, mentioning the switch number and the action to be performed. The Arduino switches on or off the switch and returns a message to the Pi.

Can this be done? I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes this can be done. But I guess you should ask something else if you want a useful answer ;)
there are many ways. we cannot decide which one you prefer. but I guess if you'd start with reading about serial communication it would help you in all of the possible solutions